# Update a document using another field than _id in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to do a partial update of a document in ElasticSearch 2.3. [The documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html) shows:

```
POST /website/blog/1/_update
{
   "doc" : {
      "tags" : [ "testing" ],
      "views": 0
   }
}
```

Is there a way to update a document using another field other than the _id (here 1) to identify the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) API and run a query which will select the documents that match the other field that you want. Basically, with that query you identify the documents you want to update following your own rules.

Comment: I am glad to have upgraded to ElasticSearch 2.3 recently as it is a new feature !